ARGON dashboard router / problems adjusting the routes
I'm having problems customizing the routes.js. I would like to go directly to the login (Login.vue) when I initially call it with / or /login. How can I customize the default routes.js correctly? The app always goes to the dashboard first.
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardLayout,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'dashboard',
        // route level code-splitting
        // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
        // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "demo" */ '../views/Dashboard.vue')
      },
      {
        path: '/icons',
        name: 'icons',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "demo" */ '../views/Icons.vue')
      },
      {
        path: '/profile',
        name: 'profile',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "demo" */ '../views/Pages/UserProfile.vue')
      },
      {
        path: '/maps',
        name: 'maps',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "demo" */ '../views/GoogleMaps.vue')
      },
      {
        path: '/tables',
        name: 'tables',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "demo" */ '../views/RegularTables.vue')
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: 'login',
    component: AuthLayout,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "demo" */ '../views/Pages/Login.vue')
      },
      {
        path: '/register',
        name: 'register',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "demo" */ '../views/Pages/Register.vue')
      },
      { path: '*', component: NotFound }
    ]
  }
];


Because you wrote above that if the slash was empty, it would first go to the dashboard and ignore the login, usually the redirection to the login is done with guards or check in your dashboard component and not in route.js

OK, thanks for the answer. I will check in dashboard weather the user is authenticated and push then to login.

Hi, can i ask you a further question?
I inserted a new route /forgot
{
path: '/forgot',
name: 'forgot',
component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "demo" */ '../views/Pages/Forgot.vue')
},
Now i want to reach the route from outside with https://myapp/forgot/ ...
How can i manage this ?

Hi, If you want to have the path /myapp/forgot, you must set the path forgot as one of the children of the path myapp, https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes

I did this, but I am always routed back to the dashboard.
I come with this external link e.g.: https://myapp.io/forgot?userId=xxx
and want to go /forgot to do some logic here.

It depends on how you have written the logic to navigate to forget, according to what you said and what I understood from your request, you should navigate like this:‌ router.push({ path: '/myapp/forgot' })

no, this is not the logic. I do not navigate with router.push.
The user gets a link to reset the password. ( see below )
When the user clicks on the link, he has to come to my page in the route /forgot.
But the router always goes to /dashboard.
https://verbux-cs.ai-vision.io/forgot?userId=f800f08c-083b-4633-94c4-511ff9a55a9a&secret=d891884059052fe00a6798a94c18273dad7be480b55a546581bd101e7008a1&expire=2024-11-11+19%3A19%3A40.175

Soved the issue. mode history did the magic. Thank you.

The process should be an automatic referral to the dashboard and within Dashboard.vue you check if the customer is inside and if not you direct them to the login
